# Redux Initial State from Server

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm curious how one manages initial state from a server. For example, we have a button, on a page, that should only be enabled if the user is authorized. I see two options, and both have cons:

1. In `ComponentWillMount()`, grab the info from the server. Con: no longer stateless.
2. In the root object, wrapped by `Provider`, get state there. Con: dumping ground for state; may never be need if the user doesn't access a particular page.

Is there a best-practice way to get initial state? I'm hoping to keep my components stateless, but if they all need some initial state, I don't see how I can keep them stateless.

** EDIT **

As a colleague pointed out, using `ComponentWillMount()` doesn't mean it's no longer stateless. I would simply dispatch my action and the state would be in Redux, not in the component itself. So #1 sounds like the way to go.

Comment: What's the fascination of keeping _every_ component stateless? Also, using a `ComponentWillMount` hook to fire an action that _initialises_ application state, I wouldn't necessarily consider that making the component itself "stateful". Particularly if it resided in a `<App />` for example.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a *fascination* of keeping *every* component stateless. It's more like trying to follow a best practice when I can. And if I need some sort of state with each component, then *none* of them will be stateless. From what I can tell, the benefits of being stateless are less code, simpler to test, and no `this` binding. So why not try?

Comment: Having said that, I think I'm starting to agree with you. It's probably better to have components with state than have 15 pages worth of initial data loaded in one spot, especially when the user won't need most of it.

Answer (score 2):

A technique I've used in SPAs is to embed initial state from the server into the page e.g.

```
<script>
    window.myAppState = { ... }
</script>
```

Much like state is set for various tracking tools do e.g. GA, Intercom etc. You can then use this to set the initial state in your reducer

```
 const initialState = new AppState(window.myAppState);
 const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => { ... };
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, state is put on the `window` object, then the reducer uses that state as its initial state? Where do you initially set `window.myAppState`? In the main page of the SPA?

Comment: @BobHorn yep, you'd set it on the server before you send the HTML page down.

Answer (score 0):

In the `index.js` after `createStore` and before `ReactDOM.render` you can do something like

```
if (localStorage.JWT) {
  const payload = decode(localStorage.JWT);
  const user = {
    token: localStorage.JWT,
    email: payload.email,
    confirmed: payload.confirmed
  };
  setAuthorizationHeader(localStorage.JWT);
  store.dispatch(userLoggedIn(user));
}
```

You can check that Token with the server if it has an expiration date, or directly dispatch any related authorization/authentication function that fetches something from the server. 
And alternatively, depending on your app logic, can redirect to the login form, or render for instance guest routes where that button is disabled. Or just that button `disable` attribute is depending on the `isAuthenticated` state in the redux.

- *I just took it from an old project, not necessarily all those
  attributes are in local storage*

Comment: Thanks for this. This closely aligns with option 2 that I listed in my post. The same cons still apply here. But I guess if I can keep it light, it may not be so bad.